# Google Translation string php error

Tags: php, translation

Hey i am making a translator and want to translate a text from language $primary to $ secondary i have used this code

```
$primary = $_POST['primary'];
$secondary = $_POST['secondary'];
 try{
       $gt = new Gtranslate;

    /**
    * Lets switch the request type to CURL
    */
    $gt->setRequestType('curl');
    $translate_string   =   $utkarsh;
$n=$gt->$primary_to_$secondary.($translate_string);
$p = urlencode($n);
```

But i am getting a error Parse error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home4/hangup/public_html/funchio.com/translate/index.php on line 23 .
```

What is Wrong with this code and any suggestions . all the variable have been defined already defined like `$utkarsh` , $ `$translate_string` and other

Comment: can you post all the code so that we can jump to line `23` to see the error

Answer (score 0):

There are some serious issues on the code..

### 1.

You forgot to add the concatenate operator.

```
$n=$gt->$primary_to_.$secondary.($translate_string);
                         //    ^----- Here
```

### 2.

Also, you need to close the `try` block..

```
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ 
    throw new exception;
}
```

Comment: i can't get it i am getting another error . this is the url where you can find whole code http://paste2.org/WKzpKFj2

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line from

```
$n=$gt->$primary_to_$secondary.($translate_string);
```

to

```
$n=$gt->$primary._to_.$secondary($translate_string);
```

Comment: i can't get it i am getting another error . this is the url where you can find whole code http://paste2.org/WKzpKFj2

Comment: i have done that but still getting error please if you can do that

Comment: The code in the link you pasted is the same as what I suggested

Answer (score 0):

Ya now i came to know i can store $primary.*to*.$secondary in new variable and then use it